# C++11 non-type template parameter bundle expansion

Tags: c++, c++11, g++4.8

While working with C++11 template parameter bundles, I came up with the code below:

```
#include <cstdio>

static void testFunc(int i1, int i2) {
    printf("testFunc(%d, %d)\n", i1, i2);
}

template <size_t... Indices> void wrapper() {
    testFunc(Indices...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    wrapper<1, 2>();    
    return 0;
}
```

An attempt to compile this with g++4.8.2 resulted in a 
`"too few arguments to function ‘void testFunc(int, int)’"` error.

Is this no valid C++ or does g++ just not yet implement this kind of non-type template parameter bundle usage?

Comment: it worked using clang 3.3-16.

Comment: Going by http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack it's perfectly valid. (See the "Function argument lists" section.)

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't mix `size_t` with `int`.

Comment: That is weird. If I add a `void testFunc(int i1) {
    printf("testFunc(%d)\n", i1);
}` it works, and correctly selects the 2-parameter `testFunc` overload. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Make sure you file a bug report.

Comment: @stefan: you're absolutely right. The type mixture remained from my  original attempt to use Indices as array offsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's valid and this appears to be a bug in gcc's variadic templates implementation. I searched a bit on the [gcc bugzilla page](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) and did not find any reports of this issue.

Comment: I couldn't find a matching report either and filed a new one: [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59978)

Answer (score 1):

I guess as a workaround you can do this:

```
template <size_t... Indices> void wrapper() {
    constexpr int x[] = {Indices...};
    testFunc(x[0], x[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! This works for the example given above but sadly not for my original problem, where I would like the wrapper to automatically adapt to the number of parameters of testFunc.